# Linux - Still `No DNS serves known` in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, ping

My `resolv.conf` in `\etc` always shows `No DNS serves`, it's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Vmware on a Windows. But my network services are all fine on my Windows, but it always show `Tempopary failure in name resolution` when I `ping` an website.
I've searched a lot on the internet, and tried [this appcted answer on askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1293852), but I still failed.

Here is my `systemd-resolve --status`:

[image: systemd-resolve --status]

[image: systemd-resolve --status]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: How does it get its IP address? Does it have an IP address?

Comment: Do you really need systemd-resolved? Try a static `/etc/resolv.conf` to avoid the configuration issues that systemd-resolved introduces.

Answer (score 1):

Please review the various ways to configure your network on a distribution that uses SystemD.   It's not comprehensive, but it may be a good start.

The combinations are endless, and you should observe the configurations used in each use-case.  Pick one, then open the toggle lists and start reading.

https://kpiq.notion.site/systemd-resolved-0c70c25bd2204cd09217d7cf61d11db4

I would recommend reviewing your /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/systemd/resolved.conf files for proper configuration.  Again, check the examples in my notes (link above).

In some cases systemd-resolved stops resolving without warning.  See one case that I encountered and fixed, documented here:

https://codeberg.org/kpiq/Tech-Space/wiki/SystemD-on-Ubuntu-22.04%2FDebian-11

Other resources can be found at:

How to switch back networking to /etc/network/interfaces on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux - Linux Tutorials - Learn Linux Configuration - Steps 7 & 8: https://kpiq.notion.site/How-to-switch-back-networking-to-etc-network-interfaces-on-Ubuntu-20-04-Focal-Fossa-Linux-Linux-T-3c37c5d6109c422ba649c0d1d43c753f

systemd-resolved: https://kpiq.notion.site/systemd-resolved-0c70c25bd2204cd09217d7cf61d11db4

Getting rid of systemd-resolved: https://kpiq.notion.site/Getting-rid-of-systemd-resolved-consuming-port-53-by-Nitin-Gurbani-Medium-b311207848a64ed9b91bcabb46d5016f

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you are running VMWare, the standard native Linux distro answers are probably not going to work for you. Have you looked at:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040304/dns-issues-with-virtualbox-vm-and-ubuntu-18-04